# Undefined method for class / calling methods outside of a class

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

```
class Computer_create

  public
  def initialize(filename)
    @@files = []
    @filename = filename
  end

  public
  def create(filename)
    @@files << filename
    puts "File: #{filename} has been created"
  end

  public
  def list
    return @@files
  end
end

file_1 = Computer_create.new("FileTest")
file_1.create("FileTest")

Computer_create.list
```

im just trying to make a simple sort of database which can make files, and store them in a Array, working on storing them in a hash though.
But every time i try out my code it gives me this:

**"computer_create.rb:24:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`list' for Computer_create:Class (NoMethodError)"**

what im trying to do is: make a file called `FileTest` via `file_1`
and then list all the files in `@@files`
but it just doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is exactly right; the class doesn't have a `list` method.

Call `list` on the *instance* of `Computer_create` you already created, e.g.,

```
file_1.list
```

In other words, exactly how you called the *other* instance method, `file_1.create`.

You're also using `@@` in an... unusual way. As far as I can tell you mean those variables to be *instance* variables, which require only a single `@`.

Unrelated, but putting `public` before each public method is noisy and unnecessary. In fact, I'd say only put `private`, once, in front of a collection of private methods.

Comment: i see your point

problem with that is...

`file_1 = Computer_create.new("FileTest")
file_1.create("FileTest")
file_2 = Computer_create.new("FileTest2")
file_2.create("FileTest2")
file_1.list
file_2.list`

it just print out that filetest 1 and 2 have been created. what im trying to do is show all the files i have in my array. but nothing shows up.